# Routing doesn't work after doing react build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So I created a routing as shown below,

```html
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import MainComponent from "./components/mainComponent";
import LoaderComponent from "./components/loaderComponent";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/home" component={MainComponent} />
      <Route exact path="/loader" component={LoaderComponent} />
      <Route exact path="/" component={MainComponent} />
    </div>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

The routing works absolutely fine when the app is started through

> npm run start

When I hit localhost:3000/home it renders the **MainComponent**.
But after the build, it says **Cannot GET /home**

> npm run build

When checking the app(after build) through nodeJs, only the default routing () works. Remaining routes throw **Cannot GET** error in the browser.

Attached below the nodejs server.js file

```html
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config();

require("./db/db_connection");
require("./scheduler");

const app = express();

//This is to make sure request body is accessible in express
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//Router for the api end points
const leaderboardRoutes = require("./routes");
app.use("/api/v1", leaderboardRoutes);

//Views are present inside build folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));

//Application hosted port
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log(`Application running on port ${port}`);
});
```

I'm also attaching the package.json file for reference,

```html
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "connect-timeout": "^1.9.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "http": "0.0.1-security",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.9",
    "node-schedule": "^1.3.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pure-react-carousel": "^1.25.2",
    "react": "^16.13.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.17",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^2.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "start-server": "npm run build && nodemon server.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Please help me in understanding what' going wrong or what I've missed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you install https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server globally and then `cd` into your built folder and start the server. Then go to browser http://localhost:8080. React compiles to static files.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used `react-scripts` but after build, if its showing `Cannot GET /*`, then it seems to me that the files are going into some directory under the `build` directory, meaning the path you're trying to access is not complete. You might want to check that and use in your build configuration.

For example, in my case, I used a mount path for my application, so it looked like:

`http://localhost:3000/myapp` where `myapp` was the mount path.

Then I had used `public` name for a directory in webpack config `path` for I wanted to put my files in there, and then I had used `publicPath` with value `myapp`, which means files were going into `build/public/myapp`, so when I hit the URL above, the server looked for `index` file in this path and loaded the file.